# Applying CSS to the correctly placed letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

At the moment this code applies the CSS style to the word once it is complete. I need it to apply the style to the individual letters to determine whether they are correctly placed or not.

```
$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));

    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2").fadeOut(1300);


        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow");

        }
    }
}
});
```

The CSS is...

```
.wordglow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 20px 7px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 20px 7px #ff0000;

}

.wordglow2 {

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 20px 7px #22ff22;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 20px 7px #22ff22;

}
```

I have tried this but have had no joy...

```
$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));

    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-letter=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2").fadeOut(1300);


        } else {
            $('td[data-letter=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow");

        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Can you post a link so we can see the problem?

Comment: @sisko did you manage to work it out by any chance?

Comment: Apologies, I looked at it but could not understand the game. By that I mean what feature do I drag where?

Comment: You drag the letters to the words, spelling the words. It is not complete yet, that is why it won't make much sense. @sisko

Comment: I see,... bear/bare :-) with me. So ... when a letter is correctly placed .. change color !??

Comment: Yes depending on whether it is right or not. At the moment it only changes color when a whole word is placed correctly or incorrectly. @sisko

Comment: I don't know if it's jsfiddle but I'm hitting a problem in my attempts ... any chance I can see the actual website?

Comment: It is in the construction stages at the moment so it isn't actually online. Whats wrong with fiddle? @sisko

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14180/discussion-between-ironspoon-and-sisko)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));
    console.log($(event).toString().toSource());
    console.log($(ui.draggable).text());

    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

        $(this).addClass('wordglow3');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('wordglow');
    }
    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2");

        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");

        }
    }


},

activate: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    // try to remove the class
    $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3');
}


 });
```